# How do you define bottom margin after a UL?

Tags: css

I want to create a custom class that controls both the space between list item and the space after the final item.

I have accomplished the first, but I can't figure out the second. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
/*Custom long list styles*/
.long-list ul {
margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.long-list li {
margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

The LI code works, but the UL code does nothing. The bottom margin ends up being whatever I set the LI to — in this case, 2px.

Comment: `.long-list` **IS** the `ul`. So, call `ul.long-list` should work. [There's no `ul` inside `.long-list`]

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However, setting the margin-bottom of the list item controls both the space between and after each bullet, and I need them to be different. For example, I need Xpx between bullets, and then Ypx after the final bullet.

Comment: Please post a working example in codepen or jsbin.

Comment: `.long-list li:last-child`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your last `<li>` to have a margin:

```
li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Or if you need a specific margin for it:

```
li {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: XXpx;
}
```